# Unable to Reconcile

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I'm quite familiar with the ArcSDE model and a few days ago we have major power issues here.

My problem (and this is a BIG one) is that one of the users, made thousands of edits correcting data, and I can't reconcile his tables.

I get a message saying that a certain feature class had a state lock. Ok, I look into Oracle, and I can see the locks, just fine. But it's the lock applied when I start the edition to reconcile.

I've tried several approaches. I'm even wondering if I could delete that specific lock from the table and try to reconcile. I tried sdegdbrepair, using the diagnose command, but it gives me 0 tables with problems.

**Edit**

The specific message is: Underlying DBMS error [owner.featuerclass][state_id = 12007].

Do you guys have ANY suggestions at all?

Could this be a permission on dbms problem? I'm at Oracle 11g.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the "But it's the lock applied when I start the edition to reconcile" remark but what I'd do in that case is have all users close edit sessions and disconnect from db (close ArcMap and ArcCatalog, stop AGS services if any), then remove locks and try again.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, then George is probably going to have to manually edit rows in multiple tables to return things to a normal state, which could require ESRI's assistance.

Comment: For removing locks in an unused db ? Not gonna happen.

Comment: We had a similar problem a couple of years ago and ended up having to manually edit the database tables so get it back to the correct state. ESRI helped us with exactly what to do, I wouldn't mess with the tables if thay haven't helped us. I don't remember the details though.

Comment: Hello guys. I could get in touch with ESRIs support because of the urgency in which we needed to get things back on track. What i did is to export the edited area (fortunately, it was a separate geographic area) and then deleted the problematic version, and loaded all over again. We lost some edits, but not as many as we would.

Comment: @George Surgery in the field is never fun.

Comment: @Michael, nice way to put it.